# how to interpret /proc/dma-mappings?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, dma

I have an android phone and when I adb to its shell, I see there is a
/proc/dma-mappings

its content looks like:

```
0xffdc0000-0xffdd0000   65536 msmsdcc_sps_init_ep_conn+0xe0/0x1f0  
0xffdd0000-0xffde0000   65536 msmsdcc_sps_init_ep_conn+0xe0/0x1f0  
0xffde5000-0xffde6000    4096 dma_pool_alloc+0x8c/0x1f4  
0xffde6000-0xffde7000    4096 dma_pool_alloc+0x8c/0x1f4  
0xffde7000-0xffde8000    4096 ehci_init+0x15c/0x384  
0xffde8000-0xffdf0000   32768 kgsl_sharedmem_alloc_coherent+0x38/0xf4  
0xffdf0000-0xffdf1000    4096 dma_pool_alloc+0x8c/0x1f4  
0xffdf1000-0xffdf2000    4096 dma_pool_alloc+0x8c/0x1f4  
0xffdf2000-0xffdf4000    8192 kgsl_sharedmem_alloc_coherent+0x38/0xf4  
0xffdf4000-0xffdf8000   16384 msm_fb_probe+0x8e8/0xedc  
0xffdf8000-0xffdfc000   16384 msm_fb_probe+0x8e8/0xedc  
0xffdfc000-0xffdfd000    4096 kgsl_sharedmem_alloc_coherent+0x38/0xf4  
0xffdfd000-0xffdfe000    4096 kgsl_sharedmem_alloc_coherent+0x38/0xf4  
0xffdfe000-0xffdff000    4096 msm_slim_init_rx_msgq+0x1cc/0x3b4  
0xffdff000-0xffe00000    4096 msm_slim_init_rx_msgq+0xb8/0x3b4
```

How to interpret this?

Comment: Those are the address range, the size, and the function that mapped it.